# CircleCI - '*** should be a either a deploy section with commands' is what?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, circleci

I'm configuring CirclCI. And trying to sync Github to AWS-EC2.
When I committed to pushed to github repo, CircleCI showed some error like this.

[image]

Here's circle.yml config.

```
test:
  override:
    - exit 0
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: develop-citest
    region: ap-northeast-1
    codedeploy:
      w***r-ma:
        application_root: /home/adbase/
        revision_location:
          revision_type: S3
          s3_location:
            bucket: w****r-vm-dev
            key_pattern: w****r-{BRANCH}-{SHORT_COMMIT}
        deployment_group: staging-instance-group
        deployment_config: CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce
```

What should I do against this problem?

Comment: Have you tried moving `region` to `w***r-ma`?